# Where to find signing certificates in Thunderbird?

Tags: email, thunderbird, certificate, pgp

I have recently installed a Linux version besides Windows on my laptop. I am now copying over important programs and settings.

I used to sign messages in Thunderbird with a certificate in Windows. I would like to import that certificate in Linux, but I have no idea where to find it or how to do this.

So my question is twofold:

- Where can I find the certificate files to sign messages in Thunderbird with?
- How can I copy them over to another installation of Thunderbird?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This depends on the kinds of certificates you want to use. You tagged [pgp](/questions/tagged/pgp), but I'm not sure whether you actually are looking for S/MIME (X.509) certificates.

### S/MIME (X.509)

Like Firefox, Thunderbird uses (unlike most other applications) its own certificate store and does not rely on the system's one.

1. open *Preferences* (in the *Edit* or *Tools* menu, depending on your operating system)
2. open the *Advanced*  tab, then *Certificates*
3. in the *View Certificates* menu, choose *You certificates*
4. select the certificates you want to export and press *Backup*, or choose *Backup All*

On the new machine, open the same certificate manager, but choose *Import*  instead.

### OpenPGP

If you use OpenPGP through Enigmail (a Thunderbird addon) and GnuPG, keys are managed by GnuPG.

Run

```
gpg --export-secret-keys [key-id] > secret-key.pgp
```

to export your key on the old machine, transfer the file to the new one, and import it using

```
gpg --import < secret-key.pgp
```

on the command line. If you prefer using a graphical user interface of your choice, it also should provide similar functionality, but make sure to also export the *secret* keys, not only public ones.

Alternatively, you could simply copy the whole `~/.gnupg` (unixoid systems) or `%APPDATA%\GnuPG` (on Windows) folder to the new machine, this will also transfer all other's keys and trust settings.